# listfragment android layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to create a layout in my fragment that allows a user to enter their workout. The fragment has an `ArrayList` of sets, and each set consists of an exercise name, sets/reps, and rest time. I can only populate so many sets at the beginning, and want to add a button at the bottom 'add exercise' in case the user wants more exercises than what the loaded layout allows...example..

Ex #1

sets/reps

rest time

Ex#2

sets/reps

rest time

[add exercise]

I tried using a listfragment and an adapter, but im not sure how I can withdraw the data that is entered into the edit text fields and save them for later use. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using adapter is a good idea.

Here is one way to achieve your goal:

When person clicks on `add exercise` button, you should get the new exercise information from the user. You can use Dialog or another activity-screen for that.

Once you got the info(sets/reps and rest time). Go and update the `ArrayList` that populates the data in the adapter. And when you done call: `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` this will make the adapter to invalidate the view based on the changes in the data(`ArrayList` in your case).